# We have to find the greatest product in a 1000-digit number taken 13 at a time adjacently....But i am not getting the true answer

Tags: python-3.x

My code is:

```
import numpy

n = '''
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450'''

num=n.split('\n')
num=''.join(num)
biggest=0

for i in range(0,len(num)-12):
    x=num[i:i+13]
    x=list(map(int,x))
    current=int(numpy.prod(x))
    if current>biggest:
        biggest=current

print(biggest)
```

Comment: What's your result?  What's the expected result?  How do we know we've fixed it if you don't give the answer?

Comment: The algorithm seems right.  Are you misinterpreting the question?

Comment: I used this to get wrong answer but i didn't know the correct answer. As i have to submit the answer on a www.project-euler.com that will only show wrong answer or right answer.

Answer (score 0):

The default datatype of `numpy.prod()` is lower precision than the answer.  I'll leave it as an exercise to fix it, since Project Euler answers should be solved yourself.